# Non-blocking I/O on graph database

Tags: nonblocking, event-driven, tinkerpop

I'm looking for a non-blocking/event-driven way to talk to a graph database.
Tinkerpop is blocking - are there any ways to overcome this?
I'm wondering if building an async rexter/rexpro client would be the way to get there or if I've overlooked something along the way. Are there any event-driven solutions for tinkerpop? And if there is not, would a rexpro client be a suitable item to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any non-blocking clients to Rexster in any language (wasn't sure about the [one for Go](https://github.com/philipsoutham/gorexpro)).  I would assume that you could build such a client over RexPro.

Note that TinkerPop3 will have such a client when "Gremlin Server" replaces Rexster.  You can read a bit more about [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/jpVPCzs3-T8/i3jfRrGXyPYJ) and how it affects the console [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/sETDv5AEUl8/KKCNeLLGIrkJ).

Comment: I really appreciate that info. I think I'm going to build the first rexpro async lib on akka io then. I cut a repo a couple days later. It might be a bit hard to drag into tinkerpop 3 but sounds like the functionality will be important in the future versions still. Thanks for the feedback